# Finding $a,b$ with two equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
16a + 4b + 1=37 \\
64a + 8b + 1=25
$$
I am having trouble find the values of $a$ and $b$ in the equation above.

Comment: Have you at least simplified this so that the constants are on one side? Then it is a problem you have no doubt seen before. You should get that $b = (4\cdot 36 - 24)/8 = 18 - 3 = 15$ and $a = -3/2$. Can you work this out?

Comment: @wol, from where did you get these equations?

Comment: @ Chris, can you show me the steps where you got a, and b.

Comment: @ Vikram, I got from the problem solving , one of the question. if you want the whole question, I can provided.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with your two equations as they are in your post $$16a + 4b + 1=37 \\
64a + 8b + 1=25$$ In a first step, move the constant froml the lhs to the rhs. This then leads to $$16a + 4b=36 \\
64a + 8b =24$$ Now, for example, multiply both sides of the first equation by $
2$ to get $$32a + 8b=72 \\
64a + 8b =24$$ Substract the first equation from the second to get $$64a-32a=24-72$$ that is to say $32a=-48$ that is to say $a=-\frac{3}{2}$. Now, use any of the first equations, replace $a$ by its value and get $b$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing now is known as simultaneous equations. There are many ways of solving them, but I'll just give you my favourite way when I was a student, no doubt more will be given.

Firstly: Group all like terms together, so since $a$ and $b$ are already consolidated, we only need to move the constants, so from
\begin{align*}
16a+4b+1&=37\\
64a+8b+1&=25 
\end{align*}
we get
\begin{align*}
16a+4b&=36\\
64a+8b&=24 
\end{align*}
Secondly: Simplify the equations. Do you see common factors within each equation? If you do, remove them, so we get
\begin{align*}
4(4a+b)&=4(9) \implies 4a+b=9\\
8(8a+b)&=8(3) \qquad\quad   8a+b=3
\end{align*}

Now, choose a variable and make it the subject of an equation (doesn't matter which variable or equation you choose, but it is wiser to choose monic variables to save trouble). I'll choose $b$ in the first equation:
$$b=9-4a.$$

Now, substitute into the other equation to get
\begin{align*}
8a+(9-4a)&=3\\
\implies 8a+9-4a&=3\\
\implies 4a&=-6\\
\implies a&=-\frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}

Lastly, substitute $a$ back into the equation to get:
$$b=9-4\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Solution confirmed

```
a = -1.5
b = 15
```

via linear equation calculator:

http://www.hackmath.net/en/calculator/solving-system-of-linear-equations?input=16a%2B4b%2B1%3D37%0D%0A64a%2B8b%2B1%3D25&submit=Calculate